# how to make folder accepted as modules in a reactjs project

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have installed a reactjs project

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
```

I have created a folder called `assets` in side `src` and added a file called `test.js` and my folder structure is as below

added `src/assets/test.js`

```
$ tree -t -I node_modules                                                                                                                                                               
.
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── README.md
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── serviceWorker.js
    ├── setupTests.js
    ├── assets
    │   └── test.js
    └── index.js
```

And in my index.js i have added

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import "assets/test.js"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Now when run

npm start

```
Failed to compile.                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                        
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'assets/test.js' in '/home/user/my-app/src'
```

How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative paths when importing,

```
import mytestFunc from "./assets/test.js"
```

If you have named exports

```
import {mytestFunc} from "./assets/test.js"
```

Comment: Some place i see they dont use `./`

because if i a have to import this from a js file inside another directory, then it will be difficult to import it. rather is there a way it treats it like modue

Comment: How to make a folder be treated as a module

Comment: If you want to treat it like a module it should be published separately as a package in npm. If you are developing this module parallely with your project, then you can use npm link to link the local module as it's not published in npm yet. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: How to publish a package: https://zellwk.com/blog/publish-to-npm/

Comment: However if you want to develop a separate module/package, don't place it inside the same repository as your React project. Best to keep it as a separate repository.

Comment: Any how i found another solution to use `"start": "NODE_PATH=./src react-scripts start",` and also installed `npm install --g cross-env` then it worked

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/. I wanted to use some paths as modules instead of using path